# Detect how long a key is held down?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to implement a simple hotkey that will do one of two actions depending on how long it was held down,

- If it was held less than `500` milliseconds do `foo`
- Else do `bar`

The `if`/`else` logic should be straight forward, I am having a hard time determining the how long its been since the key was pressed down though:

```
#singleinstance, force
#NoEnv

Space::
StartTime := A_TickCount
tooltip,% "space is down: " StartTime
return

Space up::
tooltip,% "space is up: " A_TickCount - StartTime
return

Esc:ExitApp
```

The above example, when I release `space`, the sum of `A_TickCount - StartTime` is just random small number milliseconds such as `76`, `75`, `122` even if I hold `space` for a long time. I dont think its right.

I know there a lot of scripts out there dealing but they are all dealing with Nth times a button was tapped whereas I need to know how long a key was held down.

I am confused on what `A_TickCount` is meant to represent. Is it the time since the operating system was started up? The documentation says "system" but I am not sure sure.

Comment: From the documentation (https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Variables.htm#TickCount): "The number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started, up to 49.7 days"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the Space(-down) hotkey is triggered repeatedly, therefore the random result.
To get the correct duration, use [KeyWait](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/KeyWait.htm) instead:

```
$Space::
StartTime := A_TickCount ; elapsed time in milliseconds since the system was started
tooltip,% "space is down: " StartTime
KeyWait, Space ; waits for Space to be released
tooltip,% "space is up: " A_TickCount - StartTime  ; elapsed time since the key has been pressed
return
```